# Checking if any variable in object have null/undefined/emptyString('')

Tags: javascript, string, loops, object, properties

I want to check if there is any empty field or not before submitting form. But the problem is I have variable number of fields (value1,value2...) So i can not use simple if statement. 
So is there any way i can archive this.

```
state1 = {
                vale1:'',
                vale2:'',
                vale3:'',
                vale4:''
            }

state2 = {
                vale1:'21',
                vale2:'a',
                vale3:'f',
                vale4:''
            }
state3 = {
                vale1:'fdf',
                vale2:'fgf',
                vale3:'gf',
                vale4:'hg'
            }

state4 = {
                vale1:'21',
                vale2:'a',
                vale3:'f'
            }
```

```
  functionIWant(state1) ----> false 
  functionIWant(state2) ----> false
  functionIWant(state3) ----> true
  functionIWant(state4) ----> true
```

Is there any `functionIWant` ?

Comment: To increase the chances of receiving any answers, please provide your attempt on the function. None of the built-in functions will do the trick.

Comment: You want a for loop, that will go through all values regardless of the number, i.e. you do not have to know how many values you have coming in for it to work.

Comment: do you have numbers as values? is zero a wanted value?

Comment: @Nina Scholz value can be any but not `''`.

Comment: do you have only strings as values? your question asks about `null`, `undefined` *and* empty string `''`. please add what type you have and what you want as valid value.

Comment: @Nina Scholz I have done some edit in my quetion's statement and your code is giving required results.Going to accept it.

Comment: @Ajaypayne Eriks Klotins in case you learnt something new here then you can upvote this question :-).

Comment: @RajanLagah If I learned something new here, I would upvote the answer or comment that I learned it from, not the question that asked it....
Please don't beg for upvotes

Comment: @Ajaypayne thats nice logic. But i wonder for what reason people will upvote question/s. (don't reply it's okay. have a nice day)

Comment: @RajanLagah if a question is a good question, I upvote it, if an answer is a good answer I upvote it. My point was, why would you specifically ask me to upvote your question when I only commented with one approach. Learning something new in this thread would not come from your question, but from one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the values and check every with boolean.

```js
function check(object) {
    return Object.values(object).every(Boolean);
}

var state1 = { vale1: '', vale2: '', vale3: '', vale4: '' },
    state2 = { vale1: '21', vale2: 'a', vale3: 'f', vale4: '' },
    state3 = { vale1: 'fdf', vale2: 'fgf', vale3: 'gf', vale4: 'hg' },
    state4 = { vale1: '21', vale2: 'a', vale3: 'f' };

console.log(check(state1)); // false
console.log(check(state2)); // false
console.log(check(state3)); //  true
console.log(check(state4)); //  true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript's version of `foreach` and check if any of the key value pairs have empty or null values:

```
functionIWant(state){
    //boolean to return from function, initialize to true
    let notEmpty = true;
    //Iterate the state object passed in and use javascript's version of `foreach`
    //to check if any of the key value pairs have an empty or null value
    for (let key in state){ 
        if(state[key] === null || state[key] === ''){
             notEmpty = false;
             break;
        }
    }

    return notEmpty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`Array#some()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) over the object values:

```
function functionIWant(obj) {
  return !Object.values(obj).some(v => !v || v == '');
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function functionIWant(obj) {
  return !Object.values(obj).some(v => !v || v == '');
}

const state1 = {
  vale1: '',
  vale2: '',
  vale3: '',
  vale4: ''
}

state2 = {
  vale1: '21',
  vale2: 'a',
  vale3: 'f',
  vale4: ''
}
state3 = {
  vale1: 'fdf',
  vale2: 'fgf',
  vale3: 'gf',
  vale4: 'hg'
}

state4 = {
  vale1: '21',
  vale2: 'a',
  vale3: 'f'
}
console.log(functionIWant(state1)) 
console.log(functionIWant(state2)) 
console.log(functionIWant(state3)) 
console.log(functionIWant(state4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that walks in the object properties by doing:

```js
state1 = {
  a: '',
  b: 'f',
  c: ''
}

state2 = {
  a: 'd',
  b: 'f',
  c: 'g'
}

function isValid(state) {
  return Object.values(state).every(val => val != '');
}

console.log(isValid(state1));
console.log(isValid(state2));
```

Object.values // returns all object values in an array.

```
every // you apply the predicator in all values.
```